# Return value outside of sys.exit default interval [0-127]

Tags: python, return-value, exit

Is there any way to exit with an arbitrary value from a simple python script? Actually, I'd like to return with a port number. I've read around here and in the docs as well, but found only workarounds...

Comment: The 0-127 range is a system limit, not a python limit.

Comment: Any reason why you want to use the exit code to return data instead of stdout?

Comment: Even if it was possible, it would be an ugly hack. :P

Comment: @ShawnChin: it was a requirement... I'll suggest using stdout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unix `exit` code is a **byte**. Values larger than >127 are reserved. No, you cannot reliably pass a port number via this hack. Why don't you just **print it to stdout** and parse that output?

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

> A general convention reserves status values 128 and up for special purposes. In particular, the value 128 is used to indicate failure to execute another program in a subprocess. This convention is not universally obeyed, but it is a good idea to follow it in your programs.
>
> [...] the status value is truncated to eight bits